# Rearranging the lists

Tags: list-manipulation

```
Range[1, 101, 1]
```

I have a list. Now I have to change some of the element position,
say 2 element position should come after 26,
    27 element position should come after 51,
    52 element position should come after 78,
    77 element position should come after  101,
How to do this? Actually, I have a huge amount of data, If I go about doing it manually it will be cumbersome and prone to error.

seems like it is not working for this data set

```
{0.,-0.00381335,-0.0000178914,-0.0000646514,-0.000137974,-0.000235554,-0.000355084,-0.000494261,-0.000650778,-0.000822331,-0.00100662,-0.00120133,-0.00140418,-0.00161285,-0.00182505,-0.00203848,-0.00225085,-0.00245987,-0.00266324,-0.00285868,-0.00304391,-0.00321664,-0.0033746,-0.00351552,-0.00363713,-0.00373716,0.00904689,-0.00386364,-0.00388539,-0.00387617,-0.00383354,-0.00375508,-0.00363836,-0.00348096,-0.00328047,-0.00303448,-0.00274058,-0.00239636,-0.00199943,-0.00154739,-0.00103784,-0.000468398,0.000163335,0.000859749,0.00162323,0.00245618,0.00336099,0.00434005,0.00539576,0.00653053,0.00774676,0.0646106,0.0104379,0.0119131,0.0134704,0.0151079,0.0168234,0.0186149,0.0204805,0.0224181,0.0244258,0.0265016,0.0286437,0.0308501,0.0331191,0.0354487,0.0378374,0.0402832,0.0427846,0.0453399,0.0479475,0.050606,0.0533137,0.0560694,0.0588716,0.0617191,0.144487,0.067547,0.0705232,0.0735364,0.0765838,0.0796625,0.0827698,0.0859033,0.0890604,0.0922387,0.095436,0.0986502,0.101879,0.105121,0.108373,0.111635,0.114905,0.118181,0.121462,0.124746,0.128034,0.131323,0.134614,0.137905,0.141196}
```

I am trying the same thing.

Comment: Do you mean to swap values according to their positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pos = Range[2, 101, 25];

ClearAll[f]
f = Fold[Insert[#, ##&@@ #2] &, Delete[#, List /@ pos], Transpose[{#[[pos]], pos + 24}]] &;
f@Range[101]
```

> {1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
>       21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 2, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
>       38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 27, 53, 54, 
>       55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 
>       72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 52, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 
>       89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 77}

**Update:** Using the example list in OP:

```
lst = {0., -0.00381335, -0.0000178914, -0.0000646514, -0.000137974,
 -0.000235554, -0.000355084, -0.000494261, -0.000650778, -0.000822331,
 -0.00100662, -0.00120133, -0.00140418, -0.00161285, -0.00182505,
 -0.00203848, -0.00225085, -0.00245987, -0.00266324, -0.00285868, 
 -0.00304391, -0.00321664, -0.0033746, -0.00351552, -0.00363713,  -0.00373716, 
  0.00904689, -0.00386364, -0.00388539, -0.00387617, -0.00383354, 
 -0.00375508, -0.00363836, -0.00348096, -0.00328047, -0.00303448, 
 -0.00274058, -0.00239636, -0.00199943, -0.00154739, -0.00103784, 
 -0.000468398, 0.000163335, 0.000859749, 0.00162323, 0.00245618, 
  0.00336099, 0.00434005, 0.00539576, 0.00653053, 0.00774676, 
  0.0646106, 0.0104379, 0.0119131, 0.0134704, 0.0151079, 0.0168234, 
  0.0186149, 0.0204805, 0.0224181, 0.0244258, 0.0265016, 0.0286437, 
  0.0308501, 0.0331191, 0.0354487, 0.0378374, 0.0402832, 0.0427846, 
  0.0453399, 0.0479475, 0.050606, 0.0533137, 0.0560694, 0.0588716, 
  0.0617191, 0.144487, 0.067547, 0.0705232, 0.0735364, 0.0765838, 
  0.0796625, 0.0827698, 0.0859033, 0.0890604, 0.0922387, 0.095436, 
  0.0986502, 0.101879, 0.105121, 0.108373, 0.111635, 0.114905, 
  0.118181, 0.121462, 0.124746, 0.128034, 0.131323, 0.134614, 
  0.137905, 0.141196};

lst2 = MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, lst, List /@ pos]
```

[image]

```
f @ lst2
```

[image]

```
Flatten @ Position[f @ lst2, _Style]
```

> {26, 51, 76, 101}

Comment: Seems like I having trouble for doing the same thing for  the dataset I have uploaded in the questions

Comment: @acoustics, try `f` on your posted dataset.

Comment: I tried your suggestions , but not working